# synchronizedList access by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have very basic question about the `SynchronizedList`.

Lets say I have synchronizedList as -

```
List syncList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())
```

Now my scenario is Thread A is trying to access `add()` api and Thread B trying to access `remove()` api of  synchronizedList.  Will the Both thread able to access the Both(add  and remove) api at the same time.

I believe the threads should not access the api(add() and remove()) same time.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You are right.  There is one lock and it don't matter which method you call, it is the object which is locked, not the method.

Answer (score 6):

> Will the Both thread able to access the Both(add and remove) api at
>   the same time.

The answer is no.

If you get a chance to look at `Collections.synchronizedList(List)` source code, you see that, the method is creating the instance of a static inner class named 
`SynchronizedList` or `SynchronizedRandomAccessList`, depending on the type of `List` you send as argument.

Now both these static inner class extend a common class called `SynchronizedCollection`, which maintains a `mutex` object, on which all method operations synchronize on

This `mutex` object is assigned with `this`, which essentially means that, the `mutex` object is the **same returned instance**.

Since the `add()` and `remove()` methods are performed under the

```
synchronized(mutex) {

}
```

block, a *thread* which executes `add` (and aquires lock on `mutex`), will not allow *another thread* to execute `remove` (by aquiring lock on same `mutex`), since the former has **already locked** the `mutex`. The *latter thread* will **wait** until the **lock** obtained by *former thread* on `mutex` gets **released**.

So, yes `add()` and `remove()` are **mutually exclusive**

Answer (score 1):

Can you clarify what you mean with "at the same time"?

A synchronized data structure will force one of the two threads to wait until the other has completed its operation. The "wait-on-lock" can be enforced at various levels of granularity, and can allow reads while synchronizing writes (including deletes), but the principle remains the same.

Comment: In particular, `synchronizedList` will prevent corruption of the `List` data structure but won't prevent read-update-write race conditions.

Answer (score -1):

i'd solve your problem in this way:

First i create a list wrapper class like this:

```
public class MySyncList{
   private List<String> myList;
   public MySyncList(){
      this.myList = new ArrayList<String>();
   }
   public synchronized void add(String elem){
      this.myList.add(elem);
   }
   public synchronized void remove(String elem){
      this.myList.remove(remove);
   }
   public synchronized List<String> getList(){
      return this.myList;
   }
}
```

Than access from threads:

```
final MySyncList list = new MySyncList(); // final so other threads can access it

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
   service.execute(new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
         list.add("something");
         list.remove("something");
      }
   });
}
service.shutDown();
while(!service.isTerminated());
List<String> finalList = list.getList();
```

Comment: Huh... What's the point of rewriting a `Collections.synchronizedList`?

Answer (score -1):

That is correct, the synchronized list is fully thread safe. So in terms of atomicity the threads will not able to access the list simultaneously. The access from different threads will happen in a serial manner.

Comment: It's not fullly thread safe, because iterator of that list is not thread-safe.

Comment: The question was, is the list threadsafe? Yes indeed! The iterator is a NOT a part of the list. The synchronized list itself and its internal structure is fully threadsafe.